# COUNT of items in list, with more requirements

Tags: list, workflow, calculated-column

Here's my current predicament:
I'm trying to assign a COUNT value in one list to a column in another list (on the same site, of course). But, here's the twist - 
I want a COUNT of columns of a certain NAME (Class Name being one of the fields in my first list), where the Y/N field ATTENDED (another field in first list) =Yes. So I'll end up having info along the lines of "20 people were in Class #1".

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in a calculated column OR in a workflow.  I'm open to either (which means I've tried both without success).

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- Add event receiver that will perform CAML Query and update field value(C#)
- Use CSR for executing REST call and display value in COUNT filed(JS)
- If you have Ms Workflow manager installed, you can make REST calls to the list using the 
  `Call Web Service`(WF). [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/call-http-web-service-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-spd/)